# Include member type checking in python classes generated using generateDS module

Tags: python, xsd, xml-parsing, python-generateds

Hi I am trying to generate schema class from XSD file in python using "generateDS" module.
The classes that are generated does not have type checking.
I want to generate classes that have type checking in them, so that while using the class in my code I don't have to struggle as to what is the return type of the object returned from the method

eg.
The module that is generated has two classes XSAsset and XSName
(Cannot share the xsd its client specific)

```
class XSAsset:
   def get_Name(self):
      #code block
      return self.nameType

class XSName:
   #members etc.
   def get_valueOf_():
      return self.value
```

however I want this

```
class XSAsset:
   def get_NameType(self) -> XSName|None:
      #code block
      return self.nameType

class XSName:
   #members etc.
   def get_valueOf_()->str|None:
      return self.value
```